# Quadruple Integral with 4-Spherical coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

Let the variables $x$,$y$,$z$, of $f(x,y,z)$ be on the equal status
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y,z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z  
&=\,\iiint\limits_{\substack{0\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1 \\ 0\,\leqslant\,y\,\leqslant\,1\\ 0\,\leqslant\,z\,\leqslant\,1}}f(x,y,z){\rm\,d}x\!{\rm\,d}y\!{\rm\,d}z\\  
&=\,{\color{red}{3}}\iiint\limits_{\,V_{1,(3)}\colon\substack{0\,\leqslant\,y\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1 \\ 0\,\leqslant\,z\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1}}f(x,y,z){\rm\,d}x\!{\rm\,d}y\!{\rm\,d}z\\  
\,\\  
\overset{\begin{cases}  
x=r\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\  
y=r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\  
z=r\cos\theta\\  
\end{cases}}{\overline{\overline{\hspace{4cm}}}}\quad&\,3\iiint\limits_{\,V_{1,(3)}}f(r\sin\theta\cos\varphi,r\sin\theta\sin\varphi,r\cos\theta)\,r^2\sin\theta\,{\rm\,d}r\!{\rm\,d}\theta\!{\rm\,d}\varphi\\  
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
=\boxed{3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\arctan\left(\sec\varphi\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sin\theta\cos\varphi}}f(r\sin\theta\cos\varphi,r\sin\theta\sin\varphi,r\cos\theta)\,r^2\sin\theta\,{\rm\,d}r\!{\rm\,d}\theta\!{\rm\,d}\varphi}\\ 
\end{align*}
Now, the main question is, if there is a suitable change of variables for the following integral
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y,z,w){\rm\,d}x\!{\rm\,d}y\!{\rm\,d}z\!{\rm\,d}w 
&=\,\iiiint\limits_{\substack{0\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1 \\ 0\,\leqslant\,y\,\leqslant\,1\\ 0\,\leqslant\,z\,\leqslant\,1\\0\,\leqslant\,w\,\leqslant\,1}}f(x,y,z,w){\rm\,d}x\!{\rm\,d}y\!{\rm\,d}z\!{\rm\,d}w\\ 
&=\,{\color{red}{?}}\iiiint\limits_{\substack{0\,\leqslant\,y\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1 \\ 
0\,\leqslant\,z\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1\\
\\ 0\,\leqslant\,w\,\leqslant\,x\,\leqslant\,1}}f(x,y,z,w){\rm\,d}x\!{\rm\,d}y\!{\rm\,d}z\\ 
\,\\ 
\overset{\begin{cases} 
x=\,???\\ 
y=\,???\\ 
z=\,???\\ 
w=\,???
\end{cases}}{\overline{\overline{\hspace{4cm}}}}\quad&\,?\iiiint\limits_{V_1}f(???,???,???,???)\,????\,{\rm\,d}r\!{\rm\,d}\psi\!{\rm\,d}\theta\!{\rm\,d}\varphi\\ 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
=?\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{???}^{???}\int_{???}^{???}\int_{0}^{???}f(???,???,???,???)\,????\,{\rm\,d}r\!{\rm\,d}\psi\!{\rm\,d}\theta\!{\rm\,d}\varphi\\
\end{align*}
[Wiki: N-Sphere coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)

Comment: Let $f(x,y,z)=1_{z>y>x}$, for example. then your first equation breaks down spectacularly.

Comment: yeah, you are right! @user10354138 Some conditions have been missed, let the variables $x$,$y$,$z$, of $f(x,y,z)$ are on the equal status. I have already added it now.